# touchstart event iPhone issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, html

I have a problem with touchstart event in my project . I have a menu icon and I'm doing the fallowing

```
$('.dashboard-menu').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $('.menu-state-icon').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

This works fine on desktop version , but when I open page on iPhone I have a small "delay" , so I added

```
 $('.dashboard-menu').on('click touchstart', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                //event.stopPropagation();
                $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
                $('.menu-state-icon').toggleClass('active');
        });
```

Now menu is opening faster but I can't click on menu items when I try to click on the "li" element menu close . Does anyone knows why is this happening ?

Here is the link http://djordjepetrovic.rs/touchstart/ (Menu on the center header div)

Comment: What if you uncomment it: `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: I guess you need to use something like that instead of binding both event: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18760958/1414562

Comment: Same thing, if i have just touch event , I cant click on menu items again, is it possible that its some css stuff ?