# How to get a value inside a clickHandler function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I'm trying to make my website work on all mobile devices, including iOS.
I order to do it I had to use a clickHandler function as suggested here [How to replace click with touchstart on iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201361/how-to-replace-click-with-touchstart-on-ios-devices)

I need to get a value but using $this I receive the error "is not defined".

```
<button class="open" value="{{ item.id }}">open</button>
```

```js
var clickHandler = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? "touchstart" : "click");

$(".open").bind(clickHandler, function(e) {
    var id = ($this.attr('value'));
    $("#item" + id).addClass("visible");
});
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: use `$(this).attr('value')` instead of `$this.attr('value')`

Comment: @guradio why not `$(this).val()` ?

Comment: @AminJafari it was my first answer. but then i saw it was button so i changed it to `$('this').attr('value')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, `this` is a reference to the member that invokes the current function, in your case the DOM element (button). `$()` is the jQuery constructor function. Wrapping `this` in `$()` means you are turning DOM element into jQuery object.
So what you need is either:

```
this.getAttribute("value")
```

or

```
$(this).attr("value")
```

.

`$this` has no meaning in your context, that's why you are getting undefined.